# Turn off Network Access

Tags: powershell

This is a little more of an open question than I know that is normally on here but I am trying to figure any way to use `disable-netadapter`or some other method to turn off all network adapters on a remote machine.

When we see an issue with a machine that has malware we have a .bat file that turns all the network adapters off and switches them to a static IP with no gateway, however I can't come up with a way to do this in powershell.

I am just looking for an idea of how you would do it.

Comment: Did you try `Disable-NetAdapter`? Is something not working? What? How?

Comment: How can I use Disable-NetAdapter on a remote computer to disable all adapters? once you disable the adapter you are connected on then it will kill your powershell session.

Answer (score -1):

To change the IP address of all NICs to a static IP (in this case, I'm setting them all to 10.2.2.SomeNumber.)

```
Get-NetIPAddress | ForEach-Object { $i++ 
   new-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $_.InterfaceIndex -IPAddress 10.2.2.$i}
```

We can combine that with `Disable-NetAdapter` to also disable the NIC from within Windows.  This should make sure these machines aren't able to cause too much damage!

```
Get-NetAdapter | Disable-NetAdapter
```